# how to disable intellisense in ax2012's code editor?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Is there a way to to disable intellisense in ax2012's code editor?
sometimes when writing selecting statements it's better to have it off...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Tools -> Options ->Development Tab
In the editor section, there is a checkbox for Intellisense 
[See MSDN article for setting Development Options in AX 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa572935.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need to 'turn off' intellisense, you just want to write a quick query without it interfering:

intellisense usually breaks in ax 2012 at the first sign of a compile error--just add a compile error above your query and remove it when you want intellisense back(see, it's a feature not a bug!)